# Python package sharing name with other packages

Tags: python, package

I am setting up a new development project using python. For our code we have a top-level package with the same name as our company, e.g. `acme`. We have some file io classes, so we have made a sub package `acme.io` which contains some modules. But when I try to run my code with this `acme.io` package in my path, I get errors. There is a package already called io which is imported in e.g. `gzip.py`. We made the top-level package acme to avoid this issue, since our package would be `acme.io` which would not be confused with any other packages named `io`.

My acme `__init__.py` file is empty and my acme.io `__init__.py` file imports all classes from all modules in acme.io

How can I work around this?

Comment: So your folder structure is `acme/io/__init__.py`?! Show us the errors - in principile there shouldn't be any issue with that.

Comment: Problems was that I had a folder named io, i.e C:\somehwere\io which was the base of my project. Then within io i ahde the acme package and then the io package inside there. in the acme and inner io folder I had a `__init__.py` file. In my PYTHONPATH i added c:\somewhere\io. This caused other packages to fail. When renaming c:\somewhere\io to c:\somewhere\acmeio, it all worked